# Accessing children of children's ids in KIvy

Tags: python, kivy

Sorry if the image is huge

[image: Sorry if the image is huge]

OK. So [here's my complete code](https://gist.github.com/Crowbrammer/648bc1b2b9b13a422cfc7cdb8b39c8fc). It's medium-sized, so it's just there for reference--and not required to understand the code.

So, if I want to access the Button(), Label(), or TextInput() object within a  Layout in Python, I can just do self.ids.object_name.property_of_object.

But, let's say I have a ScreenManager(), a Screen() within that ScreenManager(), and a custom layout, MyCustomLayout(), within that screen object. As far as results I've been able to get--I've not been able to get the ids from within MyCustomLayout() from the Python code for Screen().

I.e. Let's say there's an id for a button, my_button, in MyCustomLayout(). And I want to change the text.

If I'm under class MyCustomLayout(), this will work:

```
self.ids.my_button.text = 'My new text!'
```

But let's say I'm in MyScreen(), which holds MyCustomLayout(). I've not been able to get:

```
self.ids.my_button.text doesn't work
self.ids.my_custom_layout.my_button.text doesn't work
```

In fact, self.ids returns {}. It's not even populating the ObservableDict for some reason.

But, anyway. I guess what I'm saying is this. If I want to access a child of a custom widget:

1. Within a screen object
2. In Python
3. Under the MyScreen() class

How would I do it?

Thanks!

Extra Credit: Tell me how you learned about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the objects an id in kvlang. `id: mybutton`
In the following example, I set the text of the button to a random number on enter of the first screen.
In the second screen, I just print all the ids from that screen and its child, on enter.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from random import choice

Builder.load_string('''


<MyCustomLayout1>:
    Button:
        id: mybutton
        text: "Goto 2"
        on_release: app.sm.current = "screen2"


<MyCustomLayout2>:
    Button:
        id: mybutton
        text: "Goto 1"
        on_release: app.sm.current = "screen1"


<Screen1>:
    MyCustomLayout1:
        id: mylayout

<Screen2>:
    MyCustomLayout2:
        id: mylayout

''')


class Screen1(Screen):

    def on_enter(self,*args):
        self.ids.mylayout.ids.mybutton.text = str(choice(range(100)))


class Screen2(Screen):

    def on_enter(self,*args):
        print(self.ids)
        print(self.ids.mylayout.ids)


class MyCustomLayout1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyCustomLayout2(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
        self.sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
        return self.sm


MyApp().run()
```

When you nest objects, you can just do `obj.ids.obj.ids` and so on.
Even if it is not a part of the question, I can mention, that, for accessing the screenmanager from the boxlayout, it is an good idea to make the screenmanager an attribute of the App class. That way you accses it in kvlang as `app.sm`

You end your question by asking where I learned about this.
Well you got it allmost right, you just did not get the nesting right. I learned about kvlang from kivy's api reference [kvlang](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html) alltho I dont remember if it says much about nesting. But hopefully in this example, it seems like a logical way to do it.

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you answered like that. Gives me a chance to illustrate more specifically what I'm inquiring about. Let's take your code, but modify the BoxLayout part, like so -- Gist: https://gist.github.com/Crowbrammer/d78ea1a3491db095021bbabc4744b99b

Comment: As is, instantiating a custom class within the Screens produces a KeyError for 'mybutton'. If I take out lines 40-41, I get an AttributeError--'MyCustomLayout1' has no attribute 'manager' (it doesn't). So, the question is, how do we make this new code--with custom classes--work like your original code?

Comment: @crowbarProgramming ahh :) I will take a look

Comment: @crowbarProgramming updated the code. Will update the answers text a bit also

Comment: Oh that is epic. I feel relieved, and feel like I have a greater sense of control now with Kivy. Thanks--well, deserved checkmark

Comment: @crowbarProgramming Thank you. I am glad to help